# Jar File Won't Execute

Tags: java

Alrighty, so I packaged my files into an executable .jar using Eclipse, however when I try to run it by clicking or opening it informs that it "could not find or load main class Calculator.jar". 
However, if I launch it from the command prompt, (java -jar Calculator.jar), it runs like a charm. What's the issue here?

Comment: Have you defined the main class?

Comment: @Daksh Most definitely, there's only one class in the jar. The manifest seems to be fine.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean ?

Comment: @Daksh Read the whole thing ^.^

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this: [Jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html)